# VS 2019 - How to choose location for Add new project

Tags: visual-studio-2019

For a VS 2017 solution, when you right click on solution and choose add new project, in the templates page there is an option to choose the destination folder (if different from the solution folder), however it does not seem to be an option in VS 2019 preview. Is there anyway to have that option show up ? (is it even an option in 2019 ?)

To clarify - this is when you already have a solution open and are trying to add a new project to that solution

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have VS2019 preview installed.

From the start page select 'Create a new project', then select a project type. For example 'Class Library (.net Core)`and press the next button. The next screen will present you with textboxes for`Project name`,`location`,`solution name` and an option to place the solution and project in the same directory

Comment: hi, my query is not for a fresh project. For a new project from the start screen it does allow you to choose. But for an existing solution when you want to add a project it does not.

Comment: @SenthilRamanathan I'm using preview 2. If you have a solution already open in VS2019 right click on the solution and select add new project. Select the project type you want and next, then it will present you with a textbox for `project name` and  text box for `location`

Comment: yeah, see this now. Thanks. So odd as i was doing the exact same thing earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it was an issue with Resharper as well which messed up the new project dialog windows. Once that patch was installed everything worked as expected throughout. Odd issue and an even more odd fix.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-473453